# Register dependency property to inner control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a control called BasicUserControl2 which contains only a TextBox.  I would like to register a dependency property that exposes the TextBox nested inside the control.  This so that in a parent control say BasicUserControl1 I can write something like

```
<tt:BasicUserControl2 TextBox.FontSize="10" />
```

I currently have the following dependency property:

```
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get { return (TextBox)_textBox; }
        set { this.SetValue(TextBoxProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TextBox", typeof(TextBox), typeof(BasicUserControl2));
```

What kind of property do I need to register?  I am trying to avoid having to map properties on the textbox individually to identical properties on the parent UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [Attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) instead of Dependency property on your custom UserControl.